# Testing an iPhone 5C without a battery or screen

Tags: iphone, battery, screen

I have a previously broken iPhone 5c that I removed the offending parts from. The screen was shattered beyond repair, and the battery was in pretty bad condition. I'm planning to buy some new parts and repair it, but I don't want to spend around $100 and find out that other parts are broken and it's non-salvageable.

Is there a way to test the phone, maybe by making it ring or vibrate, without a battery or a screen?

#### Update:

It works, it's charging and vibrating, but it seems to be trying to notify me of something important, as it is vibrating every 3 seconds. is this normal or what

Comment: You could switch it to silent, then plug it into iTunes. That might test if it was still at all alive, then see if iTunes sees it at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin I plugged it in and iTunes doesn't seem to recognize its existence. Is there any way I could apply power to the phone without a battery? That might work.

Comment: only using another battery of the same rating

Comment: Okay, I went and dug the old battery out of the trash and I think I can reattach it and use it. Although I don't know if it's safe to do so since, well, it was in not-so-good condition when I took apart the phone, and it's been in the trash for a day, so now the casing is a bit wrinkled and it's slightly bent. It's not leaking acid or anything, but will it explode and kill me or something if I attach and charge it?

Comment: Try it let us know ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin if you don't hear from me within the next 24 hours assume I'm dead

Comment: Attached the battery and plugged in the phone, I'm not sure whether it's charging fine or the battery is broken. I'll wait a little while and try to text it

Comment: okay the phone seems to work because it suddenly started vibrating, unfortunately it keeps vibrating every 3 or 4 seconds and I don't know if this is supposed to happen or what? help

Answer (score -1):

I think on iPhones the 3 second vibratíon indicates a screen problem

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Do you have a source or other information that you can use to elaborate on this?